# Periodic function in Bloch's theorem

Tags: wavefunction, solid-state-physics, crystals

According to the Bloch's theorem, in periodic potential the wavefunction can be represented as $\Psi_{nk} = u_{nk}(r)e^{ikr}$, where $k$ and $r$ are vectors (I didn't find how to make them bold in equation, sorry) and $u_{nk}$ is a periodic function with the period of lattice constant.

I'm trying to estimate how much $u_{nk}$ depends on $k$. In my problem I have a quantity $u_{n(k+\Delta k)} - u_{nk}$, and I want to know what is my error if I neglect this term. Anselm said in his "Semiconductor theory", Appendix 21, that $u_{nk}$ depends on $k$ weakly and he neglects similar difference. Still, he didn't provide any proof, he only said "it can be shown".

Any ideas where I can find such a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it in

Sandip Tiwari - Semiconductor Physics Principles, Theory and Nanoscale, Oxford University Press, 2020

under chapter 4.6 p 153.

Comment: So from the $\mathrm{k} \cdot \mathrm{p}$ theory point of view?.. I'll try to generalize it to $\mathrm{k} \ne 0$ and if it works, I'll close the question, thank you!

Comment: Please note that link-only answers [are frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/226705) on the Stack Exchange network. It's better to explicitly provide the answer, maybe as a quotation or paraphrase of the linked-to material.

Comment: @AndreiZ. yup exactly.

Comment: @Ruslan I understand. Next time I will add some additional explaining text, but I just can't just copy all that stuff, that's the principle of references.

Comment: OK, I think I KINDA derived what I needed... not happy with it though but the duty of a scientist is to leave wishful thinking behind :( I'll publish the result (I think in supplementary materials to one of the articles) and bring it here later. Answer accepted.

Comment: @AndreiZ. Congratulations!